# Is that chinese language is easily learn from watching chinese dramas?

Tags: learning

Is that chinese language is easily learn from watching chinese dramas and is that language easy?

Comment: no language is easy to learn

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer. Whether something can be "easily learned" or not is totally subjective. Nobody here knows your language learning aptitude, your background, your exposure to Chinese, or your goals. How do you expect anybody to give you a reasonable answer?

Comment: I suggest you fix  the English in your post first -  "Can Chinese language be easily  learned from watching Chinese dramas?" And the answer is 'No'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modern drama is more easy to learn Chinese. But the true meanings of it need one's social experiences and also historical knowledge. I recommend the chinese sci-fi, also great.